# CSS nth Div with different margin

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want every second div to have `margin-right=0, border-right=0...` . I tried with css but didnt work

I am wrapping Albums in outer div `rptAlbums-wrapper` and then wrapper individual album image & title in another div `uc-album-wrapper`.

I tried `.rptAlbums-wrapper .uc-album-wrapper :nth-child(2n+1)` but this is not working

I have also set up fiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyjwF/)

```
<div class="rptAlbums-wrapper">
    <div class="uc-album-wrapper">
        <div class="uc-album-icon">
            <img alt="Album One" src="../../../../images/gallery/b9415c69-98c8-417a-960f-2adf2148c83f.jpg" class="uc-album-img" title="Album One" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ucPhotoGallery_rptAlbums_imgAlbumIcon_0">
        </div>
        <div class="uc-album-name"><span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ucPhotoGallery_rptAlbums_lblAlbumName_0">Album One</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uc-album-wrapper">
        <div class="uc-album-icon">
            <img alt="Album Two" src="../../../../images/gallery/fb1facf3-579e-4e5d-9ed8-b7f231d50f88.jpg" class="uc-album-img" title="Album Two" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ucPhotoGallery_rptAlbums_imgAlbumIcon_1">
        </div>
        <div class="uc-album-name"><span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ucPhotoGallery_rptAlbums_lblAlbumName_1">Album Two</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

UPDATED Demonstration of how it should come

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. You need to use the `:nth-child()` selector on the element itself.

```
.rptAlbums-wrapper .uc-album-wrapper:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color:Red;
    border-right:0px solid #ccc;
    margin-right:0px;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/ZyjwF/9/)

Comment: It is not working as it still show the same BK-Color and right border for both wrappers

Comment: I want first div to have following CSS `margin-right:10px` / `border-right:1px solid #ccc` and my second div to have 0 margin on right and 0 border on right and so on....

Comment: I have color coded in with red & yellow for example purpose only otherwise i dont need it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37111/discussion-between-itay-and-knowledgeseeker)

Comment: Just another [equivalent] way to skin that cat: `.uc-album-wrapper:nth-child(even)`

Answer (score 0):

Psuedo-classes, check them out:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

```
.mydiv:nth-child(2) { margin-right: 5px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the space before the colon in the line `.rptAlbums-wrapper .uc-album-wrapper :nth-child(2n+1)` (line 15 of  the css in your js fiddle example).

Comment: It is not working as it still show the same BK-Color and right border for both wrappers

Answer (score 0):

I just cleaned your HTML for my own clarity, removed the space in `.rptAlbums-wrapper .uc-album-wrapper :nth-child(2n+1)` and it is working now ...

http://jsfiddle.net/mahish/ZyjwF/10/